# Customising the placement of utm parameters in the links when sfmc is integrated with GA360

Tags: marketing-cloud

We have integrated the sfmc platform with ga360
In Journey settings we have enabled the ga auto tagging of utm parameters for appending the, to end of the link.

In one of the link in our email we have # tag at the end of the link . If the ga auto tagging is enabled the utm parameters are placed at the end of the link after the # tag. This makes the website to crash. Is there any possibility of placing the auto tagged utm parameters before the # tag in the link of the email.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue, and to my knowledge there is no workaround allowing to place the UTM characters before the anchor tag.

If you raise a case with Salesforce, you will help them prioritise this solution, as this depends on the number of users affected.